# capturing event on parent element

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

window.event reports the lowest element in the tree when a click happens. e.g.

```
<a href="http://server.com/page.aspx" id="anchor">
<span id="span" class="Someclass">
    <strong id="strong">Submit</strong> 
</span> </a>
```

When you click on the above link and if you have onclick listner at BODY level, the window.event will report that "strong" element got clicked. In the same event, how do I know that the parent is actually an "anchor" tag which has href pointing somewhere? i.e. I am looking for an automatic way for me to know the main element is "anchor" and not "strong" element. 
I clearly can't do window.event.target.parentNode.parentNode as this will be manual checking. May be somewhere I can follow the "bubbling" of the click event.

Anyone any clue?

Comment: The `<strong>` element *is* the one that got clicked. The anchor is just accidentally in the event bubbling chain, there is nothing really special about it. It's "main" only from your point of view, not from the browser's.

Comment: @Tomalak, I do see your point. Technically, there's nothing special about anchor here. I do like David's answer though...I just didn't think about that as I was so much in a rut of bubbled events. :) Thx for your input!

Answer (score 2):

You can check the ancestors automatically.

```
var element = foo;
while (foo !== document.body) {
    if (foo === someCondition) {
      return foo;
    }
    foo = foo.parentNode;
}
return false;
```

Most libraries have a method to do this built in. e.g. YUI 3 has [Node.ancestor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_ancestor), and jQuery has [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: Hmmm...thanks..I can't use YUI/jQuery as my script is standalone and want to keep very small so. I'll take a look.